# adding libsdl to Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5, sdl

I'm new to both Xcode and SDL so this may sound really NOOB!

I have tried to add sdl to Xcode but I'm not getting any good results, I found these two very good tutorials: [1st](http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/01/using-sdl-with-xcode-4/), [2nd](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/mac/xcode/index.php)

In both cases I do exactly as instructed in the tutorials linked above, but face the same problem: when I attempt to build the project, I get multiple errors listed the picture:

[image: error log]

I'm really lost and don't know where to go from here... I'd be very grateful if someone would be kind enough to tell me what to do or to point me in the right direction...

Comment: turns out the problem had nothing to do with SDL, found out more [here]

  [here]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project